# AEM workflow fails when uploading thru webdav

Tags: adobe, aem, dam

This is AEM 6.0, vanilla installation.

When uploading a digital asset via the touch interface, AEM kicks off the "DAM Update Asset" workflow and it runs to completion just fine.  However, when I copy an asset into the DAM via WEBDAV, then the workflow fails and I end up with a zero length file.

Looking in the logs I see:

```
06.01.2015 10:42:43.103 *INFO* [Apache Sling Job Queue Granite Workflow Queue] org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.TopicRoundRobinJobQueue.Granite Workflow Queue Starting job queue Granite Workflow Queue
06.01.2015 10:42:47.490 *ERROR* [10.202.41.61 [1420562565415] PUT /content/dam/xxx-www/global/en_US/cdnlive/library/Documents/_2010/cn/temp2.pdf HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.io.AssetIOHandler Failed to create revision for /content/dam/xxx-www/global/en_US/cdnlive/library/Documents/_2010/cn/temp2.pdf
06.01.2015 10:42:47.490 *ERROR* [10.202.41.61 [1420562565415] PUT /content/dam/xxx-www/global/en_US/cdnlive/library/Documents/_2010/cn/temp2.pdf HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.io.AssetIOHandler Stack Trace:
com.adobe.granite.asset.api.AssetException: Unable to create version for asset [ /content/dam/xxx-www/global/en_US/cdnlive/library/Documents/_2010/cn/temp2.pdf ]: 
    at com.adobe.granite.asset.core.impl.AssetVersionManagerImpl.createVersion(AssetVersionManagerImpl.java:83)

...

Caused by: javax.jcr.lock.LockException: Node at /content/dam/xxx-www/global/en_US/cdnlive/library/Documents/_2010/cn/temp2.pdf is locked
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.version.VersionManagerImpl.checkNotLocked(VersionManagerImpl.java:378)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.version.VersionManagerImpl.access$300(VersionManagerImpl.java:53)

...

06.01.2015 10:42:47.491 *ERROR* [10.202.41.61 [1420562565415] PUT /content/dam/xxx-www/global/en_US/cdnlive/library/Documents/_2010/cn/temp2.pdf HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.AssetImpl addRendition: cannot add new rendition [original] for asset [/content/dam/xxx-www/global/en_US/cdnlive/library/Documents/_2010/cn/temp2.pdf]: 
com.adobe.granite.asset.api.AssetException: javax.jcr.version.VersionException: Cannot set property. Node is checked in.
    at com.adobe.granite.asset.core.impl.DefaultRenditionHandler.setRendition(DefaultRenditionHandler.java:79)
    at com.adobe.granite.asset.core.impl.AssetImpl.setRendition(AssetImpl.java:127)
```

I'm at a loss were to go next.

Comment: New info: works fine using 'cp' on Linux.  The failure is only when copying from OS X.

Comment: I have given up using OS X, WebDAV, and AEM.  Just doesn't work.  Linux is all happy.